# convert integer value in json

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I am trying to make code for convert integer value in json and didn't get any solution please help me and resolve the where might be i am wrong somewhere and i have tried using parseInt but didn't get solution

```
<script>
     var userId=1;
     var status=2;
     var siteName='qualispace.com';
     var hostName='vertoz.com';
     var iabCategoreisId=1;
     var domainBlockId=1;
     var allowPubRedirection=1;
     var hostNameValidation=1;
     var pricingTypeId=1;
     var pricingTypeValue=2;
     var frequencyCap=2;
     createdDate=parseInt(123456789);
     var updatedDate=123456789;
     var createdId=1;
     var updatedId=1;
     var mobileFooterAds=1;
     var mobilePageAds=1;
     var mobileApp=1;
     var pagead=1;
     var footerad=1;
     var marginad=1;
     var entry_id=1;
     var sizeMaster=1;
     var text = '{"website":'+
                '{"userId":"'+userId+'","status":"' + 
                status + '" ,' +
                '"siteName":"'+siteName+
                '","hostName":"'+hostName+'",' +
                '"iabCategoreisId":"'+iabCategoreisId+'",,' +
                '"domainBlockId":"'+domainBlockId+'",' +
                '"allowPubRedirection":"'+allowPubRedirection+'",' +
                '"hostNameValidation":"'+hostNameValidation+'",' +
                '"pricingTypeId":"'+pricingTypeId+'",' +
                '"pricingTypeValue":"'+pricingTypeValue+'",' +
                '"frequencyCap":"'+frequencyCap+'",' +
                '"createdDate":"'+createdDate+'",' +
                '"updatedDate":"'+updatedDate+'",' +
                '"createdId":"'+createdId+'",' +
                '"updatedId":"'+updatedId+'",' +
                '"mobileFooterAds":"'+mobileFooterAds+'",' +
                '"mobilePageAds":"'+mobilePageAds+'",' +
                '"mobileApp":"'+mobileApp+'",' +
                '"pagead":"'+pagead+'",' +
                '"footerad":"'+footerad+'",' +
                '"marginad":"'+marginad+'"},' +
                '"publications":{"entry_id":"' + entry_id + '",' +
                '"sizeMaster":[{"entry_id":"' + entry_id 
                + '","adType":{"entry_id":"'+entry_id+'"}}, {"entry_id":"' 
                + entry_id + '","adType":{"entry_id":"' + entry_id + '"}}]}}';

    alert(text);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [**JSON.stringify()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

> The JSON.stringify() method converts a value to JSON, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

*Example*

```js
var newObjcet = {
  mobilePageAds: 1
};
alert(JSON.stringify(newObjcet));
```

You can create object like

```
 var text = {
    website: {
        userId : userId,
        status : status
        siteName: siteName,
        sizeMaster : [
            {
                entry_id: entry_id,
                adType : {
                    entry_id: entry_id,
                }                    
            },
            {
                entry_id: entry_id,
                adType : {
                    entry_id: entry_id,
                }                    
            }
        ]
    }
 }
```

Comment: any other solution which can i changes into my code and  i want to same in this format json

Comment: @JahangirAnsari, You should simply create Plain JavaScript object. then use the above mehod.

Comment: But sir  i am beginner in json so please help me

Comment: @JahangirAnsari, Updated answer so that you can create JavaScript object

Comment: {"website":{"userId":"1","status":"2" ,"siteName":"qualispace.com","hostName":"vertoz.com","iabCategoreisId":"1",,"domainBlockId":"1","allowPubRedirection":"1","hostNameValidation":"1","pricingTypeId":"1","pricingTypeValue":"2","frequencyCap":"2","createdDate":"123456789","updatedDate":"123456789","createdId":"1","updatedId":"1","mobileFooterAds":"1","mobilePageAds":"1","mobileApp":"1","pagead":"1","footerad":"1","marginad":"1"},"publications":{"entry_id":"1","sizeMaster":[{"entry_id":"1","adType":{"entry_id":"1"}},{"entry_id":"1","adType":{"entry_id":"1"}}]}}

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate commas here:

```
'"iabCategoreisId":"'+iabCategoreisId+'",,' +

                                         ^
```

If you just fix that, the code that you have does work to create the JSON, and the result is a valid JSON string.

You don't have to do anything to an integer value when you concatenate it into the string, it will automatically be converted to a string.

If you want some of the integer values as integers in the JSON instead of as the string representation of the number, you should remove the quotation marks around the value.

Note that some browsers (for example Firefox) won't show a string like that properly in an alert. You can use `console.log` to display the content of the string in the log window.